# windows-hosted ubuntu machine can't connect to the internet

Tags: ubuntu

I am not able to get my Ubuntu machine connected to the internet. The host machine (my PC) is a Windows PC, running Windows 10 w an AMD processor it has an ethernet cable plugged in and is working fine ○ Oracle VM VirtualBox has a Ubuntu OS machine in it Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Some of the settings are:

- Oracle VM VirtualBox> Machine> Settings> Network> Adapter 1> Attached to: NAT
- on the Ubuntu I see "Cable unplugged" at

  > Settings> Wired> "Cable unplugged"

on Ubuntu machine I did ifconfig. then tried to set the IP based in a stack post I saw:

[image: screen shot]

I notice that in other posts, ifconfig returns an IP address for the Ubuntu box. I don't even have that.

How can I get the Ubuntu box connected to the internet? Thanks.

Comment: Try Bridged Network in Virtual Box to see if Ubuntu gets internet via a Bridged connection. I have Ubuntu 18.04 as a VMware Workstation guest (not your setup) and it gets internet just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
Try `dhclient` in the console/terminal which will dynamically allocate an IP for you.
To validate ip has been assigned for you guest os, execute `ifconfig` again